# Using docker to file-sandbox a program

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sandbox

I want to use docker to achieve the following:

Run a program with access to a certain directory and then after the run reset all the changes made to that directory. I therefore wanted to create a docker image that copies said directory into the docker volume so that the program has access to the files in the directory, but the directory has the same contents for each run.

However, this seems to add a  lot of overhead - are there other (better) ways to achieve the described goal?

PS: I want to measure the behavior of the program, but not for security reasons, i.e. I trust the program.

Comment: Instead of docker, have you considered using an [overlay filesystem mount](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt)? This seems like it might meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to do the copying, that's exactly what Docker is for: keeping and discarding changes. Volumes are a way to *preserve* the files (and/or share them between containers), not for discarding them.

Once you build the image (using `docker build` and `Dockerfile`), the image acts as a starting point for containers. When you use `docker start <image>`, you create a container based the given image. The container runs a single program (called the *entry point*), and when it exits, any changes it made are either discarded (`docker container rm`) or you can start the program again from the last state (`docker start`). The same image is shared as read-only layer among all running containers so that each container only stores any differences the program makes. In the background, docker uses `overlay` filesystem to actieve this, so if you wanted, you could also do it yourself.

So the short answer is:

- Create an image containing the untouched directory
- Run the image with `docker run --rm <image>`.

(Alternatively, you can use just `docker run <image>` and delete container yourself when it exits with `docker rm <container>`).

Everythime you do `docker run`, the program will see the untouched directory as it is was stored in the image. When the program exits, any changes will be discarded. Even if you run two containers in parallel, their changes will be isolated.

Comment: What if I have multiple programs that I want to test - then I would have to create multiple images containing the directory? Would that result in multiple copy actions (one for each program/image) or not?

Comment: In that case, you could first build a base image without the program, and then build several different images from base image by just adding the program. Base image will be shared among second-level images, and containers will be started from the second-level image without even knowing it.